# multiple permissions on a binary document in marklogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

Can we add different permissions to different parts of the document?

For example book in PDF format is inserted into  database the first chapter should be freely accessible to all the users or normal users and the full book is only accessible to premium users or paid users.

How this can be implemented in MarkLogic with out maintaining free version for the original one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to add permissions to different parts of a binary document. Permissions are on the document level only.  You would need to store each chapter separately as a separate document.

MarkLogic 9 does have element level security. So in theory, if you could represent your data as XML or json, then you could give permission on the containing element. But packing binary data into elements may just be a very bad thing to do to the universal index.

If it is only the first chapter you need separately, then I would suggest that you store that as a separate document with looser permissions.

Comment: Keep in mind that element level security only allows hiding subparts to unauthorized users. Meaning, to show only one part, you'd have to hide all others.

Comment: Its a crazy solution for this case, but left it in there for education.  If I were to use this approach, I would simply structure the private part in a way to use element level security